# Node http-server persists port 8080 even after they were close

Tags: node.js, npm, port, httpserver

First, this is my configuration:

> Windows 7 Professional
>   Node v0.12.2
>   NPM v2.7.4
>   http-server v0.8.0

I've installed **http-server** using `npm install http-server -g`, still on terminal, gone to my root folder `...\node\teste` and executed `http-server -a127.0.0.1 -p8080`. Until this part everything seemed ok. The server was up and running.

When I accessed the url `localhost:8080`, it gave me a download file back as an answer, my index.js.

Shutdown the server with `CTRL+C` at the terminal, made some changes in file, up the server again and a download file as response again, but not the actual file it was the first one I've downloaded and deleted.

So, I've changed my original file name, stopped the http-server function, cleared the ports so that was not shown in `netstat -a -b` and I can still access `localhost:8080` and download the file. Even restarting my PC.

There is no node process running, I've checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After all that effort, which can be considered part of the sollution, I finally found what as the last piece of the puzzle.

I've gone to my broswer(Google Chrome) and oppened:
`Settings > Advanced Settings > Privacity > Clear Data`

And cleared all my broser data.

Then `localhost:8080` is free now.

Wanted to share this information so nobody will lost hours, like me, trying to find answers.